# Usage of TBB parallel_for_each() with reduction to Atomic counters

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, tbb, reduction

Here is my atomic counter class used for a TBB code.

```
#include <atomic>
template <typename T = int>
struct AtomicCounter {

private:
std::atomic<T> value;
std::atomic<T> num_inter;

public:
void put_inter(T niter) {
T x = num_inter.fetch_add(niter);
}

T get_inter() { return num_inter.load(); }

void increment() {  ++value; }
void put(T data) {  value.fetch_add(data) ; // ignore the old value returned }
void decrement() {  --value; }
T    get()       { return value.load(); }

};
```

I am using a parallel foreach loop in which every thread has its own local counter value and it updates the global counter object using put function of the AtomicCounter class. The function object for parallel foreach takes this global counter as a reference.

```
template<typename counter_t>
struct my_functor {
 public:
  my_functor(){}
  my_functor(counter_t &c):m_c(c){ } 

  template<typename label_t>
  void operator()(label_t label) const {

  // do some work --> local counter

   m_c.put(local_value); // put the local counter value in the global counter 
  } 

  private:
    counter_t& m_c;
    mutable int local_value; //local counter value  

  }

   // for TBB 
 //declare an object of this class as a global counter.

 AtmoicCounter<int> c;
 my_functor<atomicCounter<int>>  func(c) //functor object
 parallel_for_each( mywork.begin(), mywork.end(), func)    //TBB parallel for each
```

SO basically, each thread updates the global counter.  Is there anything wrong with the atomicCounter class where i declare the std::atomic   member ? I am using GCC 4.7.2 with C++11 features and intel TBB 4.2

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if _your_ implementation is correct, of if GCC's implementation of atomics is ok? (And if the latter, what problem have you experienced?)

Comment: @Mat- I just read somewhere that the GCC implementation of atomics in 4.7 differs from that in GCC 4.8 in terms of support for lock-free instructions. Also, I wanted to confirm if the way I have used the atomic counter for keeping the global counter value is correct?

Comment: You are packing a reduce operation into a plain `for_each`. Instead, you should use a proper a reduce function(`xxx::parallel_reduce`) and avoid the use of atomics at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem in declarations. If you are not sure in GCC atomics for some reason, use TBB atomics in which I'm sure.

But where I see the problem is usage of `mutable` keyword in order to access fields from the `const` functor. `mutable` is often mark of a bad design. And in parallel programming its usage is especially error-prone. If a method which is called in parallel marked as const, it often means that it will be called in parallel on the same instance of the functor class. Thus you have a data-race on the mutable field.

Instead of breaking the const restrictions, you can move local_value into the scope of `operator()`, or try thread-local containers `tbb::combinable` or `tbb::enumerable_thread_specific` to cache the thread-specific partial values, or apply the parallel reduction algorithm `tbb::parallel_reduce` where you can safely store partial results in functor's body.

Comment: "If a method which is called in parallel marked as const", it may also mean that it's called for a temporary instance of the functor class which will then be destroyed, as in `tbb::parallel_for`. In any case, playing tricks against constness leads to problems.

Comment: In this case, thread-safe temporary object would work since local_value seems used only in the scope of `operator()`

Comment: Correct, but the sentence is general and applicable to other cases. Anyway, I'm not disputing bur rather expanding it.